# XNA enemy wandering

Tags: c#, xna

Can anyone help me. I want my sprite to only move left and right / up and down. Then if the player goes near the enemy in a specific range of X / Y the enemy would follow the Player until the Player escape in a specific range. ( this code can only follow the player in the X coordinate )

```
class Enemy
{

        Texture2D enemy_Texture;
        Vector2 enemy_Position;
        Vector2 enemy_Origin;
        Vector2 enemy_Velocity;
        Rectangle enemy_Rectangle;
        float enemy_Rotation = 0f;

        float enemy_DistanceFromPlayer;
        float enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer;
        bool right = true;

        public Enemy(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, float distance)
        {
            enemy_Texture = texture;
            enemy_Position = position;
            enemy_DistanceFromPlayer = distance;
            enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer = enemy_DistanceFromPlayer;
        }
        float player_Position;

        public void Update(Player player)
        {
            enemy_Position += enemy_Velocity;
            enemy_Origin = new Vector2(enemy_Texture.Width / 2, enemy_Texture.Height / 2);

            player_Position = player.X - enemy_Position.X;

            if (player_position<enemy_DistanceFromPlayer)
            {
                enemy_Position += new Vector2(1, 0);
            }
            if (player_position > enemy_DistanceFromPlayer)
            {
                enemy_Position += new Vector2(-1, 0);
            }



            /*
            if (enemy_DistanceFromPlayer <= enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer)
            {
                right = true;
                enemy_Velocity.X = 1f;

            }
            else if (enemy_DistanceFromPlayer >= enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer)
            {
                right = false;
                enemy_Velocity.X = -1f; 
            }
            //if (right) enemy_DistanceFromPlayer += 1; enemy_DistanceFromPlayer -= 1;


            if (player_Position >= -20 && player_Position <= 20)
            {
                if (player_Position < -1)
                {
                    enemy_Velocity.X = 1f;
                }
                else if (player_Position > 1)
                {
                    enemy_Velocity.X = -1f;
                }
                else if (player_Position == 0)
                {
                    enemy_Velocity.X = 0f;
                }
            }*/


        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
        {
            if (enemy_Velocity.X > 0)
            {
                spritebatch.Draw(enemy_Texture, enemy_Position, null, Color.Wheat, enemy_Rotation, enemy_Origin, 1f,SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally, 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                spritebatch.Draw(enemy_Texture, enemy_Position, null, Color.Wheat, enemy_Rotation, enemy_Origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific programming problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I just want the sprite to move Left and Right / Up and Down, like a wandering AI

Answer (score 2):

An easier way would be to just go by distance instead of handling X/Y independently. Define a chase_threshold somewhere like a class-level field.

```
const float chase_threshold = 4f;  // Chase player if less than 4 squares away
```

Then this could be your chase logic:

```
float distance = Vector2.Distance(player, enemy);
if (distance < chase_threshold)
{
    Vector2 direction;

    // Should we go left/right or up/down?
    if (Math.Abs(player.X - enemy_Position.X) > Math.Abs(player.Y - enemy_Position.Y)
        direction = new Vector2(player.X - enemy_Position.X, 0);
    else
        direction = new Vector2(0, player.Y - enemy_Position.Y);

    enemy_Position += direction * enemy_Velocity;
}
```

Comment: float distance = Vector2.Distance(player, enemy);
Should I put the enemy_Position(Vector2) in the enemy(Parameter)?

Comment: It does not matter really, but yes. The Distance method of vector just takes two vectors and calculates the distance between them. Set your const minDistance and compare those two. Then set the direction with Vector2.Normalize(Player.pos, Enemy.Pos) and put a velocity to that vector to let the enemy move to the player. For direction always do Vector2.Normalize(Destination, Position).

Answer (score 0):

This is now a working Code, but the sprite keeps following me. I wanted to know how to make it stop.

class Enemy
    {

```
    Texture2D enemy_Texture;
    Vector2 enemy_Position;
    Vector2 enemy_Origin;
    Vector2 enemy_Velocity;
    Rectangle enemy_Rectangle;
    float enemy_Rotation = 0f;
    float enemy_DistanceFromPlayer;
    float enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer;
    bool right = true;

    public Enemy(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, float distance)
    {
        enemy_Texture = texture;
        enemy_Position = position;
        enemy_DistanceFromPlayer = distance;
        enemy_OldDistanceFromPlayer = enemy_DistanceFromPlayer;
    }



    Vector2 player_Position;
    Vector2 distanceFromTarget;
    float rangeToMove = 4f; // this is the range where the enemy will start to move, if the player get near it
    float distanceFromPlayer;
    public void Update(Player player, GameTime gameTime)
    {

        player_Position = new Vector2(player.X, player.Y);
        distanceFromTarget = player_Position - enemy_Position;
        distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance(player_Position, enemy_Position);
        distanceFromTarget.Normalize();
        if (rangeToMove<distanceFromPlayer)
        {
            enemy_Position += distanceFromTarget * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds * .1f;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `.1f;` is referring to the speed your enemy is chasing the player at.
If so, if you add in a speed variable where your `.1f` is for your enemy.

Try adding to your

```
float speed;

if (rangeToMove<distanceFromPlayer)
{

enemy_Position += distanceFromTarget * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds    * speed;

}
else
{
speed = 0.0f;
}
```